# iOS define color and use in xib

Tags: ios

I have defined color like this.

```
#define COLOR_BASIC_PRIMARY 0x333333
```

In xib, for label, I can set programmatically.

```
[self.lblTitle setTextColor:COLORFROMHEX(COLOR_BASIC_PRIMARY)];
```

But, I don't want to write like that and instead, I wanna take color directly from the place where I define. Is it possible ?

Comment: What do you mean by "I wanna take color directly from the place where I define"?

Comment: I mean instead of setting color programmatically, I wanna take color value that I have defined COLOR_BASIC_PRIMARY.

Comment: can u show the code for COLORFROMHEX

Comment: yes. #define ColorFromHex(rgbValue) \
[UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
green:((float)((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >>  8))/255.0 \
blue:((float)((rgbValue & 0x0000FF) >>  0))/255.0 \
alpha:1.0]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if it's possible; you can try to set it via User Defined Runtime Variables here:

[image]

Comment: thanks. i will check out for user defined runtime variables.